# como hago que los botones de una alerta me lleven a una parte de mi pagina

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, botón

tengo un boton que muestra 1 alerta con 2 botones, como hago para que esos botones me lleven a
alguna parte de la pagina o necesito otra cosa?
Mi codigo solo muestra una alerta con 2 botones

Answer (score 1):

Queres mostrar tu código de botón así puedo ayudarte mejor?

Generalmente es un  o un

Adentro de las syntaxis, va un "href" para que hagas click y te lleve a otro lado.

EJ: `<a href="https://www.google.com/">Botón a Google</a>`